# Add perpendicular symbol to a plot

Tags: r, plot

It is known that we'll use two dotted lines to express two lines are perpendicular (like the picture).

Is there any argument to express this symbol such as `symbol="perpendicular"`?

So far, I plot this symbol manually like code below.

```
plot(rnorm(10),type="n",xlim=c(-1,1),ylim=c(-1,1))
abline(h=0,v=0)
lines(c(0,0.1),c(0.1,0.1),lty=2)
lines(c(0.1,0.1),c(0,0.1),lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: @ekstroem Yes, I mean perpendicular. My native language is not English, sorry for using wrong words.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't an argument in plot that would allow you to do this. Your method seems fine to me. And also perpendicular is the correct word.

Comment: `⊥` - is perpendicular symbol

Comment: @LyzandeR Thanks for your response! Well, the figure is an illustrate plot.  In my real problem, I have lots of perpendicular symbol to draw. Hence, I wonder whether there exist an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom function:

```
#Cutom function
myfunction <- function(x, y){
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    lines(c(x[i], x[i]), c(0,y[i]), lty = 2)
    lines(c(0, x[i]), c(y[i], y[i]), lty = 2)
    }
  }


plot(rnorm(10), type="n", xlim = c(-1,1), ylim = c(-1,1))
abline(h = 0, v = 0)

myfunction(x = c(0.1,  0.5, -0.3, -0.9),
           y = c(0.5, -0.3, -0.9,  0.7))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, thanks zx8754's answer. I enjoy the idea using custom function. However, in my real case the two lines are not parallel to x axis and y axis. Hence, I write another custom function,called perpendicular, instead. BTW, any recommend will be appreciated. The code and the result are below:
[image]

```
# Make an axuliarry  line,perpendicular, from A to line OC
plot(rnorm(1),xlim=c(-7,7),ylim=c(-3,3),type="n",las=1,axes=F,xlab="",ylab="")
abline(0,-7/15,col="red",lwd=3) 
arrows(0,0,-15/4,-1/4,lwd=2,col="red")
arrows(0,0,18,0,col="gray");arrows(0,0,-9,0,col="gray")
arrows(0,0,0,10,col="gray");arrows(0,0,0,-9,col="gray")
lines(c(-15/4,-218*15/1096),c(-1/4,218*7/1096),col="red",lty=3,lwd=3)
text(-15/4,-1/4,"A",cex=2)
text(-218*15/1096,218*7/1096,"C",cex=2)
text(0,0,"O",cex=2)
#make an perpendicilar symbol to emphasis that it is perpendicular
perpendicular(-218*15/1096,218*7/1096,-15/4,-1/4,0,0,0.3)


# Given any three points,connected with two lines, perpendicualr function can draw an shape in the oppisite direction.
# Note: When two lines are perpendicular,the output will be an perpendicular symbol!
# Definition of notation:  
# (x,y) is the turning points of the shape.
# (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are the other two points.
# k is the length, depending on how large shape you want. 

perpendicular<-function(x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2,k){ 
        #points(x,y,col="red",pch=16);points(x1,y1,pch=16);points(x2,y2,pch=16)
            m1<-c(x1-x,y1-y);m2<-c(x2-x,y2-y)   #two vector of the line 
            m1<-m1/sqrt(sum(m1^2));m2<-m2/sqrt(sum(m2^2))   #standardlized the vector
            #construct the shape I want
            xx1<-c(x,y)+k*m1
            xx2<-c(x,y)+k*m2
            xx3<-c(x,y)+k*(m1+m2)
            lines(c(xx1[1],xx3[1]),c(xx1[2],xx3[2]),lty=2)
            lines(c(xx2[1],xx3[1]),c(xx2[2],xx3[2]),lty=2)
            }
```